# RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey - VerySleepy indicates that this takes a lot of time

Tags: c++, windows, profiling, visual-c++-2005, verysleepy

I'm profiling some computationally intensive code of mine, and was surprised to see that the function `RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey` takes up a huge chunk of time. It's module is `ntdll` and  the source file is `Unknown`. Is this a call which is waiting for my slow function to terminate or is it something which I can optimize?

Comment: What's the call stack above this function? As Terry mentions, it's probably not *actually* this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you have symbols for ntdll? It's possible that you don't, and RtlpNtMakeTemporaryKey is just the closet exported symbol name that your debugger can see to the real function or functions that are taking up so much time.

But yeah, you should focus on your code and who/why you're calling into ntdll so much.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an internal function in Windows since it is in ntdll.dll.  You should look at the call stack that reaches this function to find out why it is being invoked so often.

Comment: ++ Yes, and an easy way to do that is to pause it at random, as in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/1562802#1562802